# How to drop a function that is a part of a module?

Tags: db2, user-defined-functions, db2-luw

I'm using the DB2 10.1 fixpack 1 Enterprise Edition on Linux.

I would like to drop function

I checked if the function exists with:

```
select * from syscat.functions where funcschema = 'TEST' and funcname = 'REC1'
```

and have got the output:

```
ROUTINESCHEMA ROUTINEMODULENAME ROUTINENAME ROUTINETYPE OWNER OWNERTYPE SPECIFICNAME       ROUTINEID   ROUTINEMODULEID RETURN_TYPESCHEMA RETURN_TYPEMODULE RETURN_TYPENAME ORIGIN FUNCTIONTYPE PARM_COUNT LANGUAGE DIALECT    SOURCESCHEMA SOURCESPECIFIC PUBLISHED DETERMINISTIC EXTERNAL_ACTION NULLCALL CAST_FUNCTION ASSIGN_FUNCTION SCRATCHPAD SCRATCHPAD_LENGTH FINALCALL PARALLEL PARAMETER_STYLE FENCED SQL_DATA_ACCESS DBINFO PROGRAMTYPE COMMIT_ON_RETURN AUTONOMOUS RESULT_SETS SPEC_REG FEDERATED THREADSAFE VALID MODULEROUTINEIMPLEMENTED METHODIMPLEMENTED METHODEFFECT TYPE_PRESERVING WITH_FUNC_ACCESS OVERRIDDEN_METHODID SUBJECT_TYPESCHEMA SUBJECT_TYPENAME CLASS JAR_ID JARSCHEMA JAR_SIGNATURE CREATE_TIME                ALTER_TIME                 FUNC_PATH QUALIFIER IOS_PER_INVOC            INSTS_PER_INVOC          IOS_PER_ARGBYTE          INSTS_PER_ARGBYTE        PERCENT_ARGBYTES INITIAL_IOS              INITIAL_INSTS            CARDINALITY          SELECTIVITY              RESULT_COLS IMPLEMENTATION LIB_ID      TEXT_BODY_OFFSET TEXT NEWSAVEPOINTLEVEL DEBUG_MODE TRACE_LEVEL DIAGNOSTIC_LEVEL CHECKOUT_USERID PRECOMPILE_OPTIONS COMPILE_OPTIONS EXECUTION_CONTROL CODEPAGE COLLATIONSCHEMA COLLATIONNAME COLLATIONSCHEMA_ORDERBY COLLATIONNAME_ORDERBY ENCODING_SCHEME LAST_REGEN_TIME            INHERITLOCKREQUEST DEFINER SECURE REMARKS
------------- ----------------- ----------- ----------- ----- --------- ------------------ ----------- --------------- ----------------- ----------------- --------------- ------ ------------ ---------- -------- ---------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------- --------------- -------- ------------- --------------- ---------- ----------------- --------- -------- --------------- ------ --------------- ------ ----------- ---------------- ---------- ----------- -------- --------- ---------- ----- ------------------------ ----------------- ------------ --------------- ---------------- ------------------- ------------------ ---------------- ----- ------ --------- ------------- -------------------------- -------------------------- --------- --------- ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ---------------- ------------------------ ------------------------ -------------------- ------------------------ ----------- -------------- ----------- ---------------- ---- ----------------- ---------- ----------- ---------------- --------------- ------------------ --------------- ----------------- -------- --------------- ------------- ----------------------- --------------------- --------------- -------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------ -------
TEST          IZPISI            REC1        F           XXXXX U         SQL151024081854400       74258              19 TEST              IZPISI            REC1            S      S                     1                     -            -              Y                                                Y             Y                                          0                                                                  S                                                 0                                     Y                                                                                                          - -                  -                -     -      -         -             2015-10-24-08.18.54.372090 2015-10-24-08.18.54.372090 -         TEST        -1,00000000000000E+000   -1,00000000000000E+000   -1,00000000000000E+000   -1,00000000000000E+000               -1   -1,00000000000000E+000   -1,00000000000000E+000                   -1   -1,00000000000000E+000           1 -                        -               -1 -                                 0           0                -               -                  -                                      912 SYSIBM          UNIQUE        SYSIBM                  UNIQUE                                2015-10-24-08.18.54.372090                    XXXXX   Y      -
```

I tried to drop a function with:

```
drop function TEST.REC1
```

And I got the error:

```
SQL0204N  "TEST.REC1" is an undefined name. SQLSTATE=42704
```

How to drop this function?

Comment: Seems to be part of a module,  so study the `alter module` statement for your version.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ALTER MODULE IZPISI DROP FUNCTION TEST.REC1
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0054778.html

Comment: I get error: SQL0204N  "DB2INST1.IZPISI" is an undefined name.  LINE NUMBER=2.  SQLSTATE=42704. I tried: DB2 ALTER MODULE TEST.IZPISI DROP FUNCTION TEST.REC1 and got: SQL0204N  "TEST.IZPISI" is an undefined name.  LINE NUMBER=2.  SQLSTATE=42704

Comment: Checking for modules:select * from syscat.moduleobjects where objectschema = 'TEST' and OBJECTMODULENAME = 'IZPISI'  <br/>

`OBJECTSCHEMA  OBJECTMODULENAME  OBJECTNAME  OBJECTTYPE PUBLISHED SPECIFICNAME       USERDEFINED`
`TEST          IZPISI            REC1        FUNCTION   Y         SQL151024081854400 N`

Comment: `SELECT MODULESCHEMA, MODULENAME FROM SYSCAT.MODULES WHERE MODULEID=19`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ALTER MODULE TEST.IZPISI DROP FUNCTION REC1`?

Comment: @mustaccio, your suggestion returns the error: SQL0204N  "TEST.IZPISI" is an undefined name.  LINE NUMBER=2.  SQLSTATE=42704

Comment: It's strange that you have `SYSCAT.MODULEOBJECTS.USERDEFINED='N'` for this function. Try to execute the command returned by the following query as is: `select 'ALTER MODULE "'||ROUTINESCHEMA||'"."'||ROUTINEMODULENAME||'" DROP FUNCTION "'||ROUTINENAME||'"'
from syscat.routines 
where routineschema = 'TEST' and routinename = 'REC1'`. If it doesn't help, then you should open a Case with IBM support on this.